# Screenshot of complete screen with controls with scroll in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, listview

I've a screen in android, which has multiple controls like a `Listview` and `TextView` and some buttons to save the record.

If there are more question (say 15) the `Listview` is displayed in scroll bar as the `Listview` has fixed length. We have used the below code to take screenshot of the screen on save but when we have more questions in `Listview` the screen shot is taken only for the record available in the screen. Please suggest how I can take screenshot of all the questions in the `Listview` when we have more.

Code Used to take screenshot where View is the `LinerLayout` defined in `.xml` file

Sample :1

```
public Bitmap screenShot(View v) {
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            return bitmap;
        }
```

Sample :2

```
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                Drawable bgDrawable = v.getBackground();
                if (bgDrawable != null)
                    bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
                else
                    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                v.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: You mix data presentation with data itself. There's no more rows drawn than seen on the screen.